# Submit button erases all checked boxes in material ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

See the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/aewhatley/Lkuaeqdr/1/. I am trying to build a table with a submit button using Material-UI elements.

```
const {
  Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  getMuiTheme,
  RaisedButton
} = MaterialUI;

 class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const customColumnStyle = { width: 12, backgroundColor: 'yellow' };

    return (
      <div>
        <Table multiSelectable={true}>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>A</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn style={customColumnStyle}>B</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>C</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>            
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>2</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>5</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>6</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>7</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>8</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>9</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <RaisedButton label={"Submit"}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Everytime the submit button is clicked, all of the checked boxes are unchecked. Is this because render is being called again, and if so, how do I make it so that the boxes remain checked? Thanks.

EDIT: I set `selected={true}` for two of the table's rows, but I get the exact same issue:

```
const {
  Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  getMuiTheme,
  RaisedButton
} = MaterialUI;

 class Example extends React.Component {
   onRowClick = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
   }

  render() {
    const customColumnStyle = { width: 12, backgroundColor: 'yellow' };

    return (
      <div>
        <Table multiSelectable={true} onRowSelection={this.onRowClick}>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow >
              <TableHeaderColumn>A</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn style={customColumnStyle}>B</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>C</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>            
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>2</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow selected={true}>
              <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>5</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>6</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow selected={true}>
              <TableRowColumn>7</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>8</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>9</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <RaisedButton label={"Submit"}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're persisting the selected property anywhere - have you looked at the "complex example" here? http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table - as is you just have a property that's only used for each individual render and never sent/read from anywhere.

Comment: I just added selected. Same issue though.

Comment: Yeah, actually, looking at their example if you change some of the toggles it clears our selections (including what they have in there programatically).  Seems like it could be a bug in the implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I'll ask about it on their github page.

Comment: It is most likely because you need to set your `<TableBody/>` `deselectOnClickaway` prop to false. It is true by default. The Material-UI docs state that it controls whether or not to deselect all selected rows after clicking outside the table. Set it like `<TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false}>` and you will no longer have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `selected` props on the `TableRow` component.
You'll need to save the table's selected rows state before submitting, with the `onRowSelection` props of `Table` component.

Ex :

```
<Table onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}>
...
  <TableRow selected={this.state.whatever}>
  ...
  </TableRow>
...
</Table>
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not working for me. I set selected=true for two rows, and created a onRowSelection function that printed out the selected rows. See the updated JS fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because you need to set your `<TableBody/>` `deselectOnClickaway` prop to false. It is true by default. The Material-UI docs state that it controls whether or not to deselect all selected rows after clicking outside the table. Set it like `<TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false}>` and you will no longer have this issue.